# Why button is not centered vertically in LinearLayout?

Tags: android

I have a LinearLayout, which only contains one button. I want this button to be centered vertically and aligned to the right. I tried many ways, but I couldn't make this button centered vertically. It is always aligned to the top. I also tried to put a button in RelativeLayout, the button can not be centered vertically either.

The XML is as below. Is there anything wrong with this layout? Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="#E8E3E4">
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="More" 
        android:layout_gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

Changing android:layout_gravity="right" to android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" didn't resolve the problem in my question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You say in words that you want this to be centered vertically, but you have not said in *XML* that you want this to be centered vertically. You will need to adjust your `android:layout_gravity` attribute to specify both `right` and `center_vertical`.

However, I would recommend you go back to `RelativeLayout`. Use `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` to make the button be centered vertically and right-aligned.

Also, bear in mind that your current `LinearLayout` has `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, which means there is nothing to be centered inside. You need the container to have more space than its contents (e.g., `fill_parent`) if you want centering to have any meaning.

Comment: layout_gravity="center_vertical" won't work because this is a vertical LinearLayout. The right solution is to set android:gravity="center_vertical" on the LinearLayout itself.

Using a RelativeLayout is way too complicated for a case like this. The best layout in this situation is FrameLayout, then you can specify android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" on the Button.

Comment: I added android:gravity="center_vertical" on the LinearLayout itself, but the button is still not centered vertically. The modified XML is below:

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#E8E3E4"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="More" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right" />
</LinearLayout>

Comment: As I wrote above: Also, bear in mind that your current `LinearLayout` has `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, which means there is nothing to be centered inside. You need the container to have more space than its contents (e.g., `fill_parent`) if you want centering to have any meaning.

Comment: You might also wish to use `hierarchyviewer` to take a look at your activity. It will show you that there is no room for your button to be vertically centered within the `LinearLayout`. Documentation for `hierarchyviewer` can be found at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html

Comment: Yes, this worked perfect for a Horizontal LinearLayout I had inside a RelativeLayout .  This was applied to the child LinearLayout that has horizontal orientation: `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` .. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This code will put the button in vertical center and on the right screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnClick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="Click Me" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding android:gravity="center" to your LinearLayout. I remember having read somewhere that that might do the trick.